# why MySQL query is taking long time to execute and what is filtered means?

Tags: mysql, optimization, mysql-8.0

I have a query that taking a long time to execute and what is filtered means in explain plan.

Below is the MySQL query, explain plan and Structure of a table and Version is MySQL V8.0

```
SELECT  `responses`.* 
FROM `responses` 
WHERE `responses`.`survey_id` = 196690 AND (responses.time >=  '2017-01-01 08:00:00') AND (responses.time <=  '2020-10-13 13:00:58') 
ORDER BY `responses`.`id` ASC 
LIMIT 500 OFFSET 0;

CREATE TABLE `responses` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `survey_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `token` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ip_address` int(15) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `identity` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_agent` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `completed` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `completed_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `referrer` tinytext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci,
  `page` tinytext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci,
  `visible` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `mail_sent` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `anonuuid` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `metadata` json DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `survey_id` (`survey_id`),
  KEY `time` (`time`),
  KEY `index_responses_on_survey_id_and_time` (`survey_id`,`time`),
  KEY `survey_id_2` (`survey_id`,`token`),
  KEY `survey_id_3` (`survey_id`,`mail_sent`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=204788658 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC

explain 
SELECT `responses`.* 
FROM `responses` 
WHERE `responses`.`survey_id` = 196690 AND (responses.time >= '2017-01-01 08:00:00') AND (responses.time <= '2020-10-19 13:01:00') 
ORDER BY `responses`.`id` ASC 
LIMIT 500 OFFSET 0\G
```

> ```
> *************************** 1. row ***************************
>            id: 1
>   select_type: SIMPLE
>         table: responses
>    partitions: NULL
>          type: index
> possible_keys: survey_id,time,index_responses_on_survey_id_and_time,survey_id_2,survey_id_3
>           key: PRIMARY
>       key_len: 4
>           ref: NULL
>          rows: 144663
>      filtered: 0.19
>         Extra: Using where
> 1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
> ```

Comment: How much time is _a long time_?

Comment: Hi nacho, It takes more than 10 minutes to execute

Answer (score 1):

- Replace `TINYTEXT` by `VARCHAR(...)`.  TEXT columns, though essentially the same as VARCHAR have some subtle extra overhead.
- Shrink the `VARCHAR` sizes to 'reasonable' sizes.
- When you have both `INDEX(survey_id)` and `INDEX(survey_id, ...)`, get rid of the former.  Not only is it unnecessary, the Optimizer sometimes picks the former when the latter would be better.
- Change `ORDER BY id` to `ORDER BY time` (if it does not mess with the desired result too much).  *Probably* the Optimizer decided that `ORDER BY id` would be a better way to run the query than using `INDEX(survey_id, time)`.  This change to `ORDER BY` would prevent that.  I suspect that most of the table is included in that time range, and that helped confuse the Optimizer.

Here is a bigger change that will probably speed things up more:

```
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `survey_id` (`survey_id`),
  KEY `time` (`time`),
  KEY `index_responses_on_survey_id_and_time` (`survey_id`,`time`),
  KEY `survey_id_2` (`survey_id`,`token`),
  KEY `survey_id_3` (`survey_id`,`mail_sent`)
```

-->

```
  PRIMARY KEY (`survey_id`,`time`, `id`),  -- 'cluster' primarily on survey_id
  KEY(id),   -- to keep AUTO_INCREMENT happy
  KEY `time` (`time`),
```

That would essentially force the Optimizer to use the best index, and avoid bouncing between the index's BTree and the data's BTree 500 times.

(Also change the `ORDER BY` as noted above)

I don't know whether it would be worth keeping these two indexes:  `(survey_id, token)` and `(survey_id, mail_sent)`.

"Filtered" is a crude estimate of what percentage of the rows will be kept.  I rarely find it to be of any use.

I see that you are using `OFFSET`.  Does this mean you will be "paginating"?  If so, there are further issues to discuss.